# How to prevent form entry errors with radio button appearance and validation in VBA Word

Tags: vba, forms, validation, ms-word, radio-button

I am creating an electronic checklist for a manufacturing process. Operators will have a series of tasks that they must identify are complete with a Yes/No option. Originally I used check boxes but because we want to validate the form is correctly filled out, I changed them to radio buttons under ActiveX controls.  I intend to have the default value of both buttons as False so that the form appears blank when opened, then upon hitting a submit button it validates that all tasks are complete.

Originally I thought I could Group the Y/N's and iterate through opt_yes.value and opt_no.value with the group#, but that doesn't work. So Now I'm not sure how to do it without writing out code for all 19 tasks.

I've started a Function to validate my text entries:

```
Private Function EverythingFilledIn() As Boolean

    EverythingFilledIn = True

    With ActiveDocument.FormFields("Time")
    If Len(.Result) < 1 Then
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Name:="GoBackToTime"
        MsgBox "What time is it?"
        EverythingFilledIn = False
        End If
    End With

    With ActiveDocument.FormFields("Cut")
    If Len(.Result) < 1 Then
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Name:="GoBackToCut"
        MsgBox "What is the Cut Number"
        EverythingFilledIn = False
        End If
    End With
```

And I'm wondering if I can get help on the radio button validations, or an insight to looking at it a different way. I have spent a couple of weeks on forums and learned nuances of radio buttons vs. check boxes, grouping and form validating but somehow none of it has addressed my situation.

1:  The radio buttons should all be set to False upon opening template:  Done
2.  The radio button selected will be highlighted [radio1_Change()]:  Done
3.  **Upon hitting Submit button, validation will alert operator of skipped tasks: ie both button values still False = exit Sub:  Need Help Here**

Currently the radio buttons are numbered and grouped per task: ie grp_1 has radio1(y) and radio2(n); grp_2 has radio3(y) and radio4(n) etc. I was hoping that this would make it easy to iterate through.

Comment: Rather than ActiveX radio buttons (which aren't supported on Macs, if that's important), why not simply use dropdown formfields, with Yes, No & 'prompt' options?

Comment: I did that originally,  but my supervisor wants as little “time” as possible interacting with the form. Simple clicks are preferred. He literally counts every sec for efficiency.

Comment: Unless you use a dropdown, you will indeed need to write code to process all 19 sets of radio buttons. And, once you're into using code, you may as well use checkbox formfields, which you can make exclusive with VBA code. With dropdown formfields, no VBA code is required.This is an important consideration as anything that relies on VBA code is easily broken by users disabling (or failing to enable) macros or even something as simple as saving the document in the docx format.